# Proving the distance function $|f - g|_u = \sup \{ |f(x) - g(x)|: x \in S \}$ defines a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $S$ be a closed and bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Define the "functional distance" between $f$ and $g$, both functions from $S$ to $\mathbb{R}$, to be

$$
|f - g|_u = \sup \{ |f(x) - g(x)|: x \in S \}.
$$

Show that this makes the set of continuous functions from $S$ to $\mathbb{R}$ into a metric space.

---

I'm confused on how to approach this problem. Do I just need to show that

$$
|f - g|_u = \sup \{ |f(x) - g(x)|: x \in S \}.
$$

satisfies the definition of a metric given in my textbook or is there something deeper I should be thinking about? Seems that if I show that this is a valid metric, the claim follows immediately by the definition of a metric space.

Comment: That is exactly what you need to do. Prove the axioms that a distance metric must satisfy. As usual, the triangular inequality will be the difficult one (but it should not be too difficult)

Comment: Any advice on how to show the triangular inequality? I've shown the first two but am currently stuck on that last one.

Comment: Use the pointwise triangle inequality. For every $x\in S$, you have $\lvert f(x)-h(x)\rvert \leqslant \dotsc$.

Answer (score 1):

In this answer $d\left(f,g\right)$ is an alternative notation for
$\left|f-g\right|_{u}$.

Define $\left\Vert f\right\Vert :=\sup\left\{ \left|f\left(s\right)\right|\mid s\in S\right\} $ and note that $d\left(f,g\right)=\left\Vert f-g\right\Vert $.

When it comes to the triangular inequality then it is enough to prove
that $\left\Vert f+g\right\Vert \leq\left\Vert f\right\Vert +\left\Vert g\right\Vert $
because this leads automatically to: $$d\left(f,h\right)=\left\Vert f-h\right\Vert =\left\Vert \left(f-g\right)+\left(g-h\right)\right\Vert \leq\left\Vert f-g\right\Vert +\left\Vert g-h\right\Vert =d\left(f,g\right)+d\left(g,h\right)$$
It is to be shown that: $$\sup\left\{ \left|f\left(s\right)+g\left(s\right)\right|\mid s\in S\right\} \leq\sup\left\{ \left|f\left(s\right)\right|\mid s\in S\right\} +\sup\left\{ \left|g\left(s\right)\right|\mid s\in S\right\} $$
That is an immediate consequence of:

$\left|f\left(t\right)+g\left(t\right)\right|\leq\left|f\left(t\right)\right|+\left|g\left(t\right)\right|\leq\sup\left\{ \left|f\left(s\right)\right|\mid s\in S\right\} +\sup\left\{ \left|g\left(s\right)\right|\mid s\in S\right\} $
for each $t\in S$.